# How to load variable number of memory word to registers in ARM assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm

I want to load multiple memory words to registers using LDM command in ARM assembly like

```
 LDMFA    r9!, {r0-r5}  ;
```

where r9 has the address of starting memory byte to be loaded and 6 memory words are loaded to registers from r0 to r5. How can I modify this instruction so as to load a variable number of memory words? It should support loading of 1 to 12 memory words to a set of registers.

I am trying to implement copying of values from one memory location to another. User can give source start address destination start address and the number of bytes to be copied.

Comment: As auselen said, that is not possible, because of the way the instruction is encoded, maybe you should tell us what exactly you want to achieve, maybe there is a better way to do it.

Comment: See a decent memcpy implementation, it should use ldm.

Answer (score 2):

All those register numbers get embedded into instruction at compile/assembly time so there is nothing you can do to make that behaviour changeable from outside.

[image]